# Обращение к элементам массива

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Мне на выходе дается такой массив (картинка ниже), как обратиться к элементам?
Через цикл for не получается...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**

```
export class SocialBlockComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  friends: FriendBirthdayPreview[] = [];
  countBirthdays;

ngOnInit() {
    if (this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
      try {
        this.loadBirthdays();
        this.countNewBirthdays();
      } catch (Error) {
        console.log(Error.message);
      }
    }
  }

loadBirthdays() {
    this.friends = [];
    this.friendService.getFriendsBirthdays(this.profileService.getProfileInfo().id).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          response[i]['checkedBirthday'] = false;
          const friend: FriendBirthdayPreview = new FriendBirthdayPreview;
          Object.assign(friend, response[i]);
          this.friends.push(friend);
        }
      }
    );
  }

countNewBirthdays() {
    console.log(this.friends); // Выводит то, что показано в скриншоте
    for (let i = 0; i < this.friends.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.friends[i]); // Ничего не выводит
    }
  }
```

Comment: дак приведите код, как у вас не получается? дело видимо не в цикле, а в том как вы его применяете

Comment: добавте ваше решиние, тут его посмотрят и подправят если что

Comment: @Bald, какая разница, если проблема не в этом?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Тот случай когда вас обманула консоль: в ней вы видите содержимое массива на момент его отображения, а не на момент вызова `console.log` как можно было бы подумать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в этой части кода:

```
this.loadBirthdays();
this.countNewBirthdays();
```

Вы вызываете `countNewBirthdays`, еще до того как пришел ответ от сервера, вы должны переместить `countNewBirthdays` в `subscribe` после цикла `for`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    response[i]['checkedBirthday'] = false;
    const friend: FriendBirthdayPreview = new FriendBirthdayPreview;
    Object.assign(friend, response[i]);
    this.friends.push(friend);
}

this.countNewBirthdays();
```